# how to keep transaction when using `withContext` to setup a new security context?

Tags: spring, spring-security, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

In the following demo we create a new `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` to run an operation as a different user (in our actual code this is a bit more complex how we create the authentication, but for the demo the following shows the same problem as we experience).

```
@Service
final class SomeServiceImpl(
  private val repo: SomeRepository,
) : SomeService {

  @Transactional
  suspend fun foo() {
    val a = repo.save(Some())

    // expected: 1
    println(repo.count()); // actual: 1

    withContext(
      ReactorContext(
       ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(
          RunAsUserToken(
            it.userId.toString(),
            it.userId,
            it.userId,
            mutableListOf(),
            AbstractAuthenticationToken::class.java,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ) {
      // expected: 1
      println(repo.count()); // actual: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the the `repo.count()` within the `withContext` block not return 1 but 0?

When using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` the inner one returns 1 as well.

To me it seems like the transaction is lost during the context change, but I don't know how to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

## TL;DR

This:

```
withContext(
      ReactorContext(...)
)
```

... overrides the `ReactorContext` key in the `coroutineContext` (note the lower-case `c`, `coroutineContext` refers to the `CoroutineContext` in the current coroutine). Keys are overriden by `withContext` and are not merged. The `ReactorContext` key will not be merged with an already existing `ReactorContext` but overridden. Hence the existing `ReactorContext` that holds the current transaction is hidden.

### More explanation and solution

It is important to understand, that there is a `ReactorContext` in the `coroutineContext` and a new `ReactorContext` is created as argument to the `withContext`. These two `ReactorContext` exist independently of each other and require a manual merge to get a single `ReactorContext` that then can be merged to the `coroutineContext` (read: the existing one is override with the one that merges the items in the different `ReactorContext`s).

Here is an implementation that fixes the issue from the question:

```
@Service
final class SomeServiceImpl(
  private val repo: SomeRepository,
) : SomeService {

  @Transactional
  suspend fun foo() {
    val a = repo.save(Some())

    // expected: 1
    println(repo.count()); // actual: 1

    // get existing ReactorContext or create an empty one
    val reactorContext = (coroutineContext[ReactorContext] ?: ReactorContext(Context.empty()))

    // override security context in the reactorContext
   val reactorWithAuthContext = reactorContext.context.putAll(
      ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(
          RunAsUserToken(
            it.userId.toString(),
            it.userId,
            it.userId,
            mutableListOf(),
            AbstractAuthenticationToken::class.java,
          ),
        ).readOnly(),
    )

    // merge the coroutineContext with the new ReactorContext which will hide the existing ReactorContext for the withContext block
    withContext(
     reactorWithAuthContext
    ) {
      // expected: 1
      println(repo.count()); // actual: 1
    }
  }
}
```

The tricky parts for me to understand were:

1. `ReactorContext` is both, the name of the class but also (in kotlin) the name of the class refers to its companion object, which happens to be a `Key` that then is used to lookup something in the `CouroutineContext`, more clearly `coroutineContext[ReactorContext]` actually behaves like `coroutineContext[ReactorContext.Key]`.
2. Neither are there different keys for each `ReactorContext` nor do the keys in the `ReactorContext` propagate to the `CoroutineContext`. The `ReactorContext` just wraps the reactor context and makes it available to the coroutine via the `ReactorContext.Key` in the `CoroutineContext`. I assumed that the mappings in a `ReactorContext` would automatically be merged into the `CoroutineContext` which is not true.